# Controlling the the spacing between the series to avoid cluttering in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

In the highcharts example above suppose I have 100 series in **Bananas** which is 1 right now and just one series in **Apples** ,and if there is a lot of empty space between Bananas and Oranges can we reduce the spacing between them ?

The reason is if there are 100 series in **Bananas** due to space constraint every line gets overlapped even though there is extra space available between Bananas and Apples . Also is it possible to remove "Oranges" if it doesnt have any series at all and accomodate only series from **"Bananas"**?

Comment: Kindly share code you attempted

Comment: There is a lot of different ways you an do this, depending on your config and data. [`columnPadding`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPadding) and [`groupPadding`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding) are two of the parameters that will help with this. Some combination will probably be necessary. And of course it is possible to remove "Oranges", but again, depends on your data and the rest of your config.

Answer (score 0):

Categories functionality works only for constant tick interval equaled to 1. What you're trying to achieve is having a different space reserved for every category. That means that tick interval has to be irregular.

Unfortunately Highcharts doesn't provide a property to do that automatically - some coding and restructuring the data is required:

1. All the points have specified x position (integer value)
2. `xAxis.grouping` is disabled and `xAxis.pointRange`is `1`
3. Following code is used to define and position the labels:

   ```
   events: {
     render: function() {
       var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

       for (var i = 0; i < xAxis.tickPositions.length; i++) {
         var tickPosition = xAxis.tickPositions[i],
           tick = xAxis.ticks[tickPosition],
           nextTickPosition,
           nextTick;

         if (!tick.isLast) {
           nextTickPosition = xAxis.tickPositions[i + 1];
           nextTick = xAxis.ticks[nextTickPosition];

           tick.label.attr({
             y: (new Number(tick.mark.d.split(' ')[2]) + new Number(nextTick.mark.d.split(' ')[2])) / 2 + 3
           });
         }
       }
     }
   }
   (...)
   xAxis: {
     tickPositions: [-0.5, 6.5, 7.5],
     showLastLabel: false,
     labels: {
       formatter: function() {
         switch (this.pos) {
           case -0.5:
             return 'Bananas';
           case 6.5:
             return 'Apples';
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2Lcs5up5/